# REST Response - What's "expected" in an HTML response vs JSON or XML

Tags: html, json, rest, response

General question re. what's "expected" when sending an HTML response vs JSON or XML for example for the same data.

Say I've got an array of USER information. With JSON or XML I'd just convert that array to the desired format and return the array.

But with HTML? Is it expected that the same array will just be converted to a text string (text/html) and return that so it's still just the array being returned?

Or is it expected that my USER array will be printed to an html template, and that template is what gets returned as my HTML response?

Interested to know what the correct way to return HTML is.

Comment: For best performance, just send the JSON and use a client side (or both) templating language.

Comment: you mean HTML or XHTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data will be the exact same string regardless, then you can only expect that the MIME type that is sent through the HTTP Request's header will one of those.

For example, you could send {"a": 1} and send it as `plain/html` and it wouldn't be accessible by javascript without a separate step to encode it into JSON. Instead, sending it as `application/json` is going to make javascript understand it correctly.

So, that same sort of thing applies to html and xml. send the correct mime type for the correct actual data and then you can parse it and handle it properly.